# Can you use ORDER BY (column) LIMIT with a secondary column?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, sql-order-by

I want to find out the Top 10 rented movies in the [sakila db.](https://database.guide/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/sakila_full_database_schema_diagram.png)
It must be sorted DESC after total_rentals and secondary after film title.
My solution looks like this and works so far without the film title:

```
SELECT COUNT(rental_date) AS total_rentals, f.title
FROM rental r 
LEFT JOIN inventory i USING (inventory_id) 
LEFT JOIN film f USING (film_id)
Group by f.title
ORDER BY total_rentals DESC LIMIT 10, f.title 
;
```

However, I can't sort it after film.title due to syntax error(Error 1064).

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `LIMIT` comes after `ORDER BY`, not in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ORDER BY total_rentals DESC, f.title  LIMIT 10
```

This guarantees just 10 rows in the resultset, sorted by descending `total_rentals`, then by film title.

Another way to read your question: give me the 10 best rental scores, and the associated movies - which may yield more than 10 rows if there are ties. In that case, I would recommend window functions (available in MySLA 8.0)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rentals, f.title,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM rental r 
    INNER JOIN inventory i USING (inventory_id) 
    INNER JOIN film f USING (film_id)
    GROUP BY film_id, f.title
) t
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY total_rentals DESC, title
```

Notes:

- `COUNT(*)` is more efficient than `COUNT(<something>)` and is equivalent here
- I wouldn't expect "orphan" rows in `rental`; if so, `INNER JOIN`s are more appropriate than `LEFT JOIN`s
- It is probably a good idea to add `film_id` to the `GROUP BY` clause, in case there are title homonyms